# Use Texmaker to do Beamer Presentation, fail to generate pdf file with math symbols

Tags: beamer, texmaker

My problem is that:

(1) When I just type normal words or numbers like, `$123+456=2$`. Texmaker works well, and pdf file can be generated.
[image]

(2) However, when I use slightly complicated math symbols, like `$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$`. I press F6 and the pdf file can be built.
[image]

However, when I press "View pdf", error log pops up and shows "File not found."

(3) I do google the problem and find the old posts in tex stack exchange but no solutions are found. I provide what I was required installed today:
[image]

Since I am going to present my final year project next week, thank you you guys who can give me a hand. I appreciate it very much. Orz...

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{David, chole}
\title{How to display math}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

%\begin{frame}
%\tableofcontents
%\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to SE.TeX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Could you paste your .tex file inside your question?

Comment: @ppr Thank you for your comments. I have added my code in the question. I am new to tex stack exchange so that I may not do it properly. Thank you for your teaching.

Comment: This code works fine for me. There is probably a lack in your LaTeX installation. Could you paste the error message (in Texmaker > F10).

Comment: Thank you for your helping. I think the log is at the screen captured above. When I press "View pdf", it just pops up this (plz click inside):
http://i.na.cx/096v7.png

Comment: The screenshots in your question are for the unproblematic `$123+456=2$` operation.

Comment: @ppr Please check it: http://i.na.cx/AA09n.png It is quite strange that no errors were found in log but when I press "View Pdf", it just cannot show up. Is it problem with my packages installed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13935/discussion-between-nam-and-ppr)

Comment: Error cannot be reproduced with current pdflatex.